# You don't have permission to access with react native

Tags: php, sql, react-native

I have a react native application with PHP Backend and SQL server DB .

This application  was working so fine .but today when I tried to run it ,it begins giving me this kind of problems.

This is my function in react native :

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.9:80/netOne/recup.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({email:usermail,password:password,})})
   .then((responseData)=>responseData.text())
   .then((responseJson)=>{
   if(responseJson =='Data Matched'){this.props.navigation.navigate( 'Welcome')}
   else{alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));}})
```

When I consult php page from my navigator i got :

[image]

But in my application ,it's showing :

[image]

Comment: check your file permissions first of all. Make sure the Apache user account has permission to read the PHP file.

Comment: Can you explain more how to check the permissions

Comment: just normal filesystem permissions. You know how to check that, hopefully? If not it's easy to find out how, just get the right instructions for your operating system. And find out which user account Apache is running under.

Comment: Thaks for ur help , I resolved my problem.